# The Date & Time for TFS locks

Tags: tfs, locking

Is there a way to see the date and time when a file was locked in TFS?

Just to be clear, I am not talking about check-ins. Only locked/check outs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS, **Locks** appear as a "*pending change*" for the person who locked the item. As long as the lock is in effect, it will appear as a pending change. When a commit is made of that pending change, the lock is released.

While the lock is in effect, the locked branch is effectively read-only, since (to simplify) the locker is the only user who can make commits. The act of committing is what releases any locks on the branch.

So the lock operation is first occurs at local side and will not be recorded by TFS. You could only get who locked the branch and check the branch status is locked or not  at the moment. There is no way to query when a file/branch was locked in TFS. You could also take a look this similar question: [when a file was locked in TFS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb2db585-8221-4086-8da8-48057ca36e28/tfs-branch-lock-who-locked-or-unlocked-the-branch-on-which-day-or-at-what-time?forum=tfsadmin)